# Match a non-specific number of records with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a function on an ASP.NET website I'm building that allows users to register for multiple categories in a particular event. Site administrators need to be able to add these categories and also to add rules that govern which groups of categories attract a discount.

My solution was to create a header table called CategorySelectionRule, which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CategorySelectionRules (
RuleId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
RuleDescription VARCHAR(100),
RuleMessage VARCHAR(255),
Discount DECIMAL
)
```

...and a detail table called CategorySelectionRuleDetail which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CategorySelectionRuleDetail (
RuleCategoryId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
RuleId INTEGER REFERENCES CategorySelectionRules(RuleId),
CategoryId INTEGER REFERENCES EntryCategory(CategoryId)
}
```

So if someone enters category 1 and 4, the code checks for a rule that contains these categories (and only these categories), then returns the discount and message that apply.  My problem is that the code is getting out of control, as I need to allow for any number of categories in a rule, but I can't figure out how to do that without a select case that joins the detail table back on itself, like this, which only works for rules with two categories (Oh, and it doesn't actually work):

```
categoryRuleId = (From r1 In _db.CategorySelectionRuleDetail _
                  Join r2In _db.CategorySelectionRuleDetail _
                    On r1.RuleId Equals r2.RuleId _
                  Where ((r1.CategoryId = matchCategory1 _
                  AndAlso r2.CategoryId = matchCategory2) _
                  OrElse (r1.CategoryId = matchCategory2 _
                  AndAlso r2.CategoryId = matchCategory1)) _
                  AndAlso !(From r3 In _db.CategorySelectionRuleDetail  _
                            Group r3 By r3.RuleId Into g_
                            Where g.Count(RuleId) > 2).Contains(r1.RuleId) _
                  Select r1.RuleId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Is there a better way to do this that I'm not seeing? I feel like the data structure is right, but I'm sure there's an easier way to match the data I want without resorting to separate LINQ statements for each number of categories.

Answer (score 0):

This Linq Statement will do what you want:

```
var rules = from r in db.CategorySelectionRules
                   where r.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.Count() == selectedCategories.Count &&
                         r.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.Where(cr => selectedCategories.Contains(cr.CategoryId.Value)).Count() == selectedCategories.Count
                   select r;
```

This will also pass back multiple rules if there are two different rules that have the same category requirements.

**Full Program:**

**SQL used to generate database structure**

```
CREATE TABLE EntryCategory ( 
CategoryId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
CategoryDescription VARCHAR(100)
) 

CREATE TABLE CategorySelectionRules ( 
RuleId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
RuleDescription VARCHAR(100), 
RuleMessage VARCHAR(255), 
Discount DECIMAL 
) 

CREATE TABLE CategorySelectionRuleDetail ( 
RuleCategoryId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
RuleId INTEGER REFERENCES CategorySelectionRules(RuleId), 
CategoryId INTEGER REFERENCES EntryCategory(CategoryId) 
)
```

**C# Program (Console App)**

```
namespace StackOverFlowTesting
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Load Data
      using (var db = new DatabaseDataContext())
      {
        //Check to see if the data has already been loaded
        if (db.EntryCategories.Count() == 0)
        {
          //Load in inital categories
          db.EntryCategories.InsertOnSubmit(new EntryCategory() { CategoryDescription = "Category1" });
          db.EntryCategories.InsertOnSubmit(new EntryCategory() { CategoryDescription = "Category2" });
          db.EntryCategories.InsertOnSubmit(new EntryCategory() { CategoryDescription = "Category3" });

          //Load in inital rules
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule1", RuleMessage = "Rule1 Message", Discount = .5M });
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule2", RuleMessage = "Rule2 Message", Discount = .5M });
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule3", RuleMessage = "Rule3 Message", Discount = .5M });
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule4", RuleMessage = "Rule4 Message", Discount = .5M });
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule5", RuleMessage = "Rule5 Message", Discount = .5M });
          db.CategorySelectionRules.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRule() { RuleDescription = "Rule6", RuleMessage = "Rule6 Message", Discount = .5M });

          //Link up the categories and rules
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 1, RuleId = 1 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 1, RuleId = 2 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 2, RuleId = 2 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 1, RuleId = 3 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 2, RuleId = 3 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 3, RuleId = 3 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 1, RuleId = 4 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 3, RuleId = 4 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 2, RuleId = 5 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 3, RuleId = 5 });
          db.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(new CategorySelectionRuleDetail() { CategoryId = 3, RuleId = 6 });

          //Populate the database with our temp records
          db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        /** Different ways of testing **/
        //var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 1 }; //Rule 1
        var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 1, 2 }; //Rule 2
        //var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 1, 2,3 }; //Rule 3
        //var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 1, 3 }; //Rule 4
        //var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 2, 3 }; //Rule 5
        //var selectedCategories = new List<int>() { 3 }; //Rule 6

        var rules = from r in db.CategorySelectionRules
                   where r.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.Count() == selectedCategories.Count &&
                         r.CategorySelectionRuleDetails.Where(cr => selectedCategories.Contains(cr.CategoryId.Value)).Count() == selectedCategories.Count
                   select r;

        if (rules.Count() == 0)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("No rule found");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine(rules.Count().ToString() + " Rules Found");
          foreach (var rule in rules)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(rule.RuleDescription);
          }          
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```